# When a person replies with a sentence starting with "then"/"than", should it be then or than?

Tags: grammar

I've heard people sarcastically respond with sentences of the form "then [effect of persons actions]" even though the person was not soliciting for advice.

For example
Joe: "I wrote my paper on why George Bush was a good prime minister for Canada"
Jane: "Then you are going to get a bad mark"

Should it be "then" or "than"? Initially I thought "than" as it shows the relationship between writing a poor paper and receiving a poor mark, but since it's talking about something hypothetical that may happen in the future it would be "then".

Comment: It should be _then_ if it comments on the results of something expressed by a previous clause, or on the timing of events after some event mentioned in a previous clause. It should be _than_ if it comments on a comparison mentioned in a previous clause; _than_ is limited to comparative constructions -- A: "He's a better player." B: "Than anybody in the league, of just his team?"

Comment: Often then is conflated to than when typing. It's common typo.

Answer (score 5):

"Then".

"Then" refers to the sequence of actions. "Than" refers to a comparison between two things. In your example, "you are going to get a bad mark" follows, and is the effect of, "I wrote my paper on why George Bush was a good minister for Canada".

Since the second action results from the first, we are dealing with time order, and "Then" is appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you are looking for "Then" because "then" is a transition word that helps communicate a sequence of events.  In this particular example though, I might suggest the word "consequently" or even the phrase "in that case," as they may be more clear.